# Factory-girl: 'association' named column overlap with Factory method named 'association'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have the following Factory definition.

```
Factory.define :status do |f|

end 

Factory.define :my_status , :parent => :status do |f|
  f.association 'something_here'
  f.alias 'something_here'
  f.name  'something_here'
end
```

I know about the factory defined 'association' method, something like:
       f.association :group, :factory => :group
But I actually have a column named association.  What will be the way to assign values to my column?

Update:
One way to solve came to me after Maletor's post - Thanks Maletor

I added this to my status model

```
  alias_attribute :assoc, :association
```

and now I can do

```
Factory.define :my_status , :parent => :status do |f|
  f.assoc 'somthing_here'
  f.alias 'somthing_here'
  f.name  'somthing_here'
end
```

Works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

You could assign it in an `f.after_create`. Not as elegant though. Renaming the column might not be a bad idea either.

Comment: This is a good way , the problem is that I am pre-loading those Factory and it won't work in my case. Renaming the table column is not an option , but that brough the ide of creating an alias in the model for this column . I added that to my description above